# how to work with promise in play 2.0 framework

Tags: asynchronous, akka, future, promise, play2-mini

i am working play 2.0 application with java.In that i am using promise for the Asynchronous sending of email.For that i followed http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaAsync

I tried like this:

```
Promise<Result> promiseOfInt = Akka.future(
        new Callable<Result>() {
        public Result call() {
        try {
        sendMail(form,to,sub,msg);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; }  }  );
```

Then i got this error:
[WARN] [09/07/2012 19:34:40.737] [New I/O  worker #14] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [akka.actor.promises-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher

I am new to the async programming in play.I am not getting how to handel the promise. Can any one help me.Kindly provide sample example. Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a warning, but if it bugs you (like it did me) you'll need to add Akka configuration to your Play project.

See here [Akka Configuration Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html) for a sample of the file akka.conf.  Put it in the /conf folder and add `include "akka.conf"` to application.conf

In order to configure the promises dispatcher, make sure yours includes:

```
akka { actor {
 ...
 promises-dispatcher = {
  throughput = 10 # For example
 }
 ...
}}
```

See other settings at [Akka Dispatcher Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#Setting_the_dispatcher_for_an_Actor)